# Bit shifting a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, bit-shift, randomaccessfile

I need to bit shift everything in a `RandomAccessFile` that is to the right of the file-pointer four bytes to the right so that I can write an integer into it at the file pointer.

This will not compile:

```
raf >> 16;
```

I was going to use `readFully()` (which reads bytes from the RAF starting at the pointer) and then go from there, but that reads them into an array and a restriction of the project is that we can't use arrays.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is that you are trying to do? You want to insert a integer in between while reading a file?

Comment: Yes its a binary insert. The user enters a number and the program inserts in the correct place in the file (its sorted in ascending order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) "works" on a physical file, it reads from and writes to a file.

You can't just insert bytes into a position. All the bytes after the position have to be moved, copied to allow space for the value you want to insert.

The most efficient way would be to read the remaining data into an array, insert (write) the new value and write back the array. But you said this is not allowed.

Alternatively you have to use a loop (e.g. `for`) to iterate over the bytes and write them back to a greater position (the amount you want to insert: +4 bytes).

Assuming the file length and current position is a multiple of 4 bytes (which suits your needs), here is an example how to do it:

```
public static void insert(RandomAccessFile raf, int dataToInsert)
                      throws IOException {

    // First remember insertion position:
    long insPos = raf.getFilePointer();

    // Next copy all data from this pos. For easier, go downward:
    raf.seek(raf.length() - 4);

    for (long pos = raf.getFilePointer(); pos >= insPos; pos -= 4) {
        // readInt() and writeInt() implicitly moves the file pointer
        raf.writeInt(raf.readInt());
        raf.seek(pos - 4);
    }

    // Copy done, insert new value:
    raf.seek(insPos);
    raf.writeInt(dataToInsert);
}
```

### Example Usage

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("a.txt", "rw");
// Position file pointer where we want to insert:
raf.seek(4);
insert(raf, 0x41424344); // This is "ABCD" in text representation
```

**Input:**

```
123456789012
```

**Output:**

```
1234ABCD56789012
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped me to finish the project. The professor did mention in class that we should use a bit shift, but it wasn't a requirement, so it's all good.

Comment: I'm working with very big files(sound files) with over 40Gb and I'd like to shift the contents, to add extra metadata but iterating over each byte in the billions that the file has, seems prohibitely computationally expensive, isn't there anything to help solving this matter? Like batch shifting or something like that? This answer was very helpful nonetheless

Comment: @ManelPereira Of course you can do that. E.g. if you know you want to insert 100 bytes, then extend the file with 100 bytes, and start copying the content, from the end. E.g. read last 1 MB, and copy it 100 bytes higher position. Then 1 MB before the last, and so on, until you reach the position where you want to insert.

Comment: @icza Ooh I see... That way i avoid reading each byte thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is to sort integers and store it in a file, it might be worth to try [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/)

> MapDB provides concurrent Maps, Sets and Queues backed by disk storage
>   or off-heap memory. It is a fast embedded Java database engine with
>   Apache license.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but using a RandomAccessFile is part of the project requirements.